# Create DataFrame column from a groupby

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Suppose I have a DataFrame like

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Id'    : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
    'Group' : [1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3],
    'Value_to_compare' : [2,1,5,8,2,3,10,23,17],
    'Other_value' : [0,3,2,6,3,4,2,7,1]
})
```

I would like to create a new column, say `Value_of_Highest`, displaying for each row `Other_value` of element having the highest `Value_to_compare` of its `Group`. For example, here:

- Group 1 has 2 elements, its highest `Value_to_compare` is 2, for `Id` = 1, for which `Other_value` is 0
- Group 2 has 4 elements, highest `Value_to_compare` is 8, for `Id` = 4, for which `Other_value` is 6
- Group 3 has 3 elements, highest `Value_to_compare` is 23, for `Id` = 8, for which `Other_value` is 7

So I would like to add a column so that df becomes

[image]

This is the best way I know to do this:

```
def my_func(x):
    x = x.sort_values('Value_to_compare',ascending = False)
    Value_of_Highest = x.head(1)['Other_value'].values[0]
    return pd.Series([Value_of_Highest], index=['Value_of_Highest']) 

grouped = df.groupby('Group').apply(my_func).reset_index()

df = df.merge(grouped)
```

I am pretty sure there is a far more elegant and efficient way to do this in Python/Pandas.

Edit: after first answer from @CameronRiddell, I realized my example was flawed. I corrected it and @CameronRiddell edited his answer, which works well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great application of `groupby` and `transform` essentially, using transform from a groupby object applies a function to each group, but then returns a Series or DataFrame of the same size as that group. This results in DataFrame/Series whose shape is the same as the original shape along the groupby axis. (e.g. in your case, the result of a groupby/transform will have the same number of rows as your original dataframe).

```
df["Value_of_Highest"] = df.groupby("Group")["Value_to_compare"].transform("max")

print(df)

   Id  Group  Value_to_compare  Other_value  Value_of_Highest
0   1      1                 2            0                 2
1   2      1                 1            3                 2
2   3      2                 5            2                 8
3   4      2                 8            6                 8
4   5      2                 2            3                 8
5   6      2                 3            4                 8
6   7      3                10            2                23
7   8      3                23            7                23
8   9      3                17            1                23
```

- `df.groupby("Group")`: group the dataframe by our "Group" column
- `["Value_to_compare"]`: From each of those groups, select the "Value_to_compare" column
- `.transform("max")`: Get the maximum value of our selected column for each group. Then return a Series who has the same number of rows as the group

---

Edit: To obtain a value based on the location of a maximum, we use `idxmax()`. This returns the position where a max/min occurs. So for our use case:

- we'll groupby "Group" and select the "Value_to_compare" column
- Then we get the index of the maximum values of "Value_to_compare"

```
highest_vtc_indices = df.groupby("Group")["Value_to_compare"].idxmax()

print(highest_vtc_indices)
Group
1    0
2    3
3    7
Name: Value_to_compare, dtype: int64
```

0, 3, 7 corresponds to the row ID where the maximum values of "Value_to_compare" occur in each group.

Now that we know the row these maximums occurred in:

- We'll need to subset our original dataframe to get the "Other_value" in each of these rows
- We'll also need to get the "Group" column associated with these rows, so that we can align these values properly later

```
# Obtain "Group" & "Other_value" at rows 0, 3, 7
  # which were the rows for each highest Value_to_compare per group
highest_other_values = df.loc[highest_vtc_indices, ["Group", "Other_value"]]

# Rename Other_value to Value_of_Highest
highest_other_values = highest_other_values.rename(columns={"Other_value": "Value_of_Highest"})

print(highest_other_values)
   Group  Value_of_Highest
0      1                 0
3      2                 6
7      3                 7
```

Now that we have the corresponding "Other_value" to the maximum "Value_to_compare" per group, we'll use a `merge` to align our new smaller dataframe back to our original dataframe. This will broadcast "Value_of_Highest" across the "Group" column from the original dataframe.

```
# Merge this new dataframe back to our old one to broadcast "Value_of_Highest" across each group
final = df.merge(highest_other_values, on="Group")

print(final)
   Id  Group  Value_to_compare  Other_value  Value_of_Highest
0   1      1                 2            0                 0
1   2      1                 1            3                 0
2   3      2                 5            2                 6
3   4      2                 8            6                 6
4   5      2                 2            3                 6
5   6      2                 3            4                 6
6   7      3                10            2                 7
7   8      3                23            7                 7
8   9      3                17            1                 7
```

Comment: Wow! I think you saved my code mate!!! Thank you very much!

Comment: it is not exactly that, though, since you duplicated `Value_to_compare` instead of `Other_value`.

Comment: CameronRiddell I realize that my example didn't exactly reflect what I was asking. I have edited so it shows values from `Other_value` instead of `Value_to_compare`. I'm still lost, could you kindly help?

Comment: I've updated my answer to address this edit! (kept my original answer and put the new one below it)

Comment: Wonderful, thank you very much indeed! I will think about `idmax()` next time I need this kind of thing. :)

Comment: Great! If this answered your question and you don't have any other questions would you mind selecting this answer as correct so that others who stumble across this question can know this method worked for you?